# Using Access DB to populate Combo boxes

Tags: c#, ms-access

I've read just about every article, but everything seems out dated, or using SQL. I'd like to populate a combobox with users from my DB. I was able to get the login feature using the DB as reference;

```
AppdataTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter user = new AppdataTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter();
Appdata.UsersDataTable dt = user.UsernamePassword(usernametxt.Text, passwordtxt.Text);
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have DataTable variable say for example dt holding list of users you'll only need following code. Suppose your combo boxes name is ddl

```
ddl.DataSource = dt;
ddl.DataBind();
```

It is somewhat like this make sure with your intellisense feature in visual studio.